# Responded to employer for job, then created account. Where is the message thread?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

According to the email I received from the employer, sent by do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com, I could reply to this email to respond to the employer's message. Below that, it suggested I join Stack Overflow to view the full message thread as well as review my application/resume for the job posting this message was related to.

I hadn't signed up for Stack Overflow with that particular email (my professional email) so went for it. From this point, I can't seem to find any reference to this email chain, application/resume review and, generally speaking, no proof that my response was sent.

Where can I find this information? Can I assume the employer received my response?

Verbatim, the bottom of the email says "You can respond to company by replying to this email.

Join Stack Overflow to view the full message thread, review your application for position, ask questions about interesting roles, receive interest from companies, and more."

The native email app on Android doesn't appear to respect reply-to in headers. This issue goes back as far as 2009 from what you can see.

This issue is present on the email app v. 6.75.14.

Comment: I'd love to check that for you. Can you send me your email address you replied from via email? find my address on my profile. Thanks!

Comment: @g3rv4 emailed you :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After following up with kotlx via email, here's what happened:

When we send an email to a candidate with an employer message, we send the following headers with it:

```
From: "Employer Name (Stack Overflow)" <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com>
Reply-To: reply-XX-YY-ZZ@reply.talent.stackoverflow.com
```

The [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.2) says that, when present, email clients should be sending replies to the address specified on the `Reply-To` header... but his email client replied to `do-not-reply@` (the one in the `From` header) instead.

This wouldn't have been a big deal if we rejected that (he would have noticed something wasn't ok almost immediately)... but right now, `do-not-reply@` doesn't send anything back. It just fails without any kind of feedback.

I provided him with his particular reply-to address, he sent the response there, and now that message has been successfully received by the employer.

**What we're doing to ensure this doesn't happen again:**

1. When we receive an email at `do-not-reply@`, avoid failing silently. **DONE**
2. <s>Move away from this `Reply-To` pattern</s> (punted, potentially for ever)

- After going this way and giving it a try, we found a couple issues:

  - We need to ensure DMARC validations pass for the the reply subdomain
  - We need to have our code handle bounces (they are sent to `do-not-reply@` right now)
  - There're many things that break by doing what I thought was a trivial change (it was live for a couple minutes and I learned this the hard way).
- This is why we will keep the `Reply-To` header in the short term. We expect that the auto-responder (which we will be implementing today) provides enough feedback to people using odd email clients to know that something went wrong.

Comment: Could I also suggest that you change "You can respond to company by replying to this email." (assuming that **is** quoted verbatim) to "You can respond to the company by replying to this email." - If I received an email with poor grammar like that, I would immediately think it was a phishing scheme.  "receive interest from companies" is also poorly worded, and would typically imply a phishing attack.

Comment: We're currently using "You can respond to `<companyName>` by replying to this email", which is better IMO, as you know who you'd be replying to ;)

Comment: "There're many things that break by doing what I thought was a trivial change (it was live for a couple minutes and I learned this the hard way)." was there, did that. Yep.

Comment: +1 for learning the hard way. :D