# Please reply to do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

I've recently been getting a few emails from recruiters about jobs via Stack Overflow jobs. This is exactly what I hoped would happen when I toggled that setting in my profile. However, the "sender" of the emails themselves is a little misleading:

[image][image]

The email body explicitly says that I can respond by replying to the email. However, the email address that I'm replying to is a "`do-not-reply@`" address. I've been conditioned to believe that I shouldn't reply to addresses with that username :-). Nothing is broken *per se*. The replies seem to work just fine. This is more just a fine-point to alleviate possible user confusion.

I would suggest sending the email from a different email address. I'm not sure that I have the brainpower right now to suggest a great alternative -- Maybe `recruiters@stackoverflow.com` or `reply-to-<companyName>@stackoverflow.com` or even `ajkl78971hkjhaf@stackoverflow.com`.

<sup>Sorry if this has been asked before -- This seems to have been alluded to in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344415/responded-to-employer-for-job-then-created-account-where-is-the-message-thread), but as far as I can tell, that question is asking something completely different and just mentions it as a side-detail.</sup>

Comment: Let's keep it simple and classy: `do-reply@stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @BSMP That is a common way to allow communication between two parties through an intermediary without revealing real addresses.

Comment: Maybe just a simple `jobs@stackoverflow.com` since this is an email that comes and goes back to SO Jobs?

Comment: What's wrong with `user<ID>@stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: The recruiter might not be a member on the site and even then you don't want to reveil such information @Raphael

Comment: What email client are you using? We set the `Reply-To` address which should be used in preference of the from address by all sane clients. We can't use a pseudo-email address for the from because of some DMARC crazy.

Comment: I know that at least Windows Mail 10 [doesn't respect the `Reply-To` header](https://medium.com/@BraunDoug/windows-10-mail-client-broken-ignores-reply-to-header-f64b6a58365f) @DeanWard. Last I checked (few months ago) this still wasn't fixed. Microsoft and Email is still a toxic combination it seems :-/

Comment: This feature is working as intended; ignoring the email address is the first interview challenge.

Comment: They could make it into a tagline.  "Are you really going to let an email address tell you what to do?  Reply today!"

Comment: @DeanWard -- This is using Google's "Inbox" client.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker it's as if the app was developed from scratch by a team with no prior mail client experience. Similar issue with the W10M "Outlook" app, it's impossible to configure IMAP folders. You'd think Microsoft knows how to write mail clients after a couple decades...

Comment: Sorry recruiters. The very best developers don't actually reply to your job emails. They are too busy posting about them on meta.

Comment: You can still forward a message or create a new message. No reply needed.

Comment: @bitnine But you should actually reply the next day, because you shouldn't let a tagline tell you what to do, either.

Comment: We, as developers, played one of the most important roles in the hi-tech world what it is today. Even a 0.1% probability of a misinterpretation in the flow must be considered as a probable input. In addition to this, the system should be self explanatory and not contradictory. I voted this question up because @mgilson highlighted this contradiction with SO. The simplest solution can be [recruiter's id/username]@stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 18):

Let me clarify a bit how the "reply by email" feature works.

When an employer sends you a message, we send you an email that has the following headers:

```
From: "Employer Name (Stack Overflow)" <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com>
Reply-To: reply-XX-YY-ZZ@reply.talent.stackoverflow.com
```

Even if you see that the `From` is `do-not-reply`, if you reply to the email (and your email client... does what it's supposed to do), you will end up sending an email to `reply-XX-YY-ZZ@reply.talent.stackoverflow.com`. Based on XX, YY and ZZ we will process your email (that means: sending an email to the employer and adding your message to the thread on our system).

As commented [by Dean](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350303/please-reply-to-do-not-replystackoverflow-com#comment479600_350303) and [myself on the linked post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344441/920295), we tried getting rid of it (and only sending the dynamic address on the `From` header)... but we found out that:

1. Doing so broke DMARC validation for those emails, getting them bounced by some email providers.
2. The code that handles the replies to/from candidates is not prepared to handle bounces (they're sent to the address on `From`, not on `Reply-To`). Then it started treating them as emails to/from candidates and spamming some users lots of bounces.
3. And here's one that I love: If we used the dynamic email address on the `From` header... all the auto replies (we have *a lot* of them on our `do-not-reply` box) would be included in the conversation.

Considering that:

- [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.2) says that, when present, email clients should be sending replies to the address specified on the `Reply-To` header.
- A user with a well-behaving email client can reply to that email and it's sent to the appropriate party.
- We have an auto reply at `do-not-reply@` so that users with bogus email clients get a notification that something didn't work with their message.

We will not invest time in killing `do-not-reply@`.

Comment: Instead of "killing do-not-reply", how about you keep it and invest some time in a second static email address with a better name that still handles all the concerns you mentioned?

Comment: @TylerH I'm not following, are you asking us to rename it? so make it `jobs@stackoverflow.com` but if you email there, we send an automated response saying that it's not monitored? why would that be better?

Comment: `donotreply@stackoverflow.com` automatically routes email replies to recruiters, no? So 'monitoring' is not really the issue. Just send recruiter emails to users via a different name like `recruiters@stackoverflow.com` or yes even `jobs@stackoverflow.com`, and when people reply to them as instructed, the replies are routed to the recruiter like they currently are. How would that not be better than getting "reply to this email" instructions from a "do not reply" address?

Comment: @TylerH nope, `do-not-reply` doesn't route email replies to recruiters. Dynamic email addresses like `reply-XX-YY-ZZ@reply.talent.stackoverflow.com` (which we send on the Reply-To header) do. But we can't send from those email address due to the DMARC validation and multiple email providers plain out bouncing them.

Comment: So OP's whole post then is based on a false premise? Replies to a recruiter email sent via `donotreply@stackoverflow.com` in fact *don't* get seen by anyone? I have never used SO Jobs so I don't know for sure what email address is being blocked out in OP's image, but he makes it sound like it came from `donotreply@stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: @TylerH I totally see the confusion. I've edited my answer with details about how the feature works. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Ironically, a heavily downvoted and deleted answer made this argument originally.

Comment: You could consider setting an _on-behalf-of_ header with the same value as the _reply-to_ header. Then, in most mail clients, it's evident that you can reply to it, and to which address that reply will go, and that fixes this UX problem. However, it's not a standard header, so support may vary.

Comment: @TylerH: The problem is in many mail clients giving the false impression that any replies to an email go to the one listed in the From: header, regardless of the presence of a Reply-To: header, *even if they correctly address the user's reply to the Reply-To: when they begin composing a reply*.

Answer (score -21):

I think this should remain as is; it appears to be working as intended.

By default, all outgoing mail will come from this address, but if you inspect the mail headers, or even just  click the reply button, you WILL be sending mail to a different address.

Here are some headers from one of my recruitment messages, i've omitted / changed some uuids.

```
From: "(S** M**) Stack Overflow" <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com>
To: matt@mclarkdev.com
Reply-To: reply-200000-100000-5fa24abddd8b40d9ddd24a998dc6100b@reply.talent.stackoverflow.com
```

By simply clicking `Reply`, any mail client you use *should* properly handle this.

If something like `jobs@stackoverflow.com` were used, people might wrongfully get the impression that this would be the address to reply to; and if the 'Reply-To' header does not work properly, their messages will be routed into a blackhole - those message may never make it back to the correct recruiter. Using `do-not-reply` accurately conveys the fact that if this is your destination, the messages will not be read.

Comment: What could *possibly* be the point of tricking people into thinking they can't reply.

Comment: There is no trick here, there is one 'authorized' address that mails should be sent from, and this helps to not have the domain flagged for spam. If a user clicks reply and sees this address, they _should not reply_, as the address says, this mailbox is not monitored. Having a specific address per message, or even recruiter, it a great way to get your domain flagged.

Comment: The Reply-To field should be all you need, and this is something that is used not just by Stack Exchange, but organizations around the world. Not sure why I am getting tons of downvotes for explaining why this works the way it does.

Comment: Not all e-mail clients show the reply-to address before hitting the "reply" button. It really seems counterintuitive to reply to a mail, sent from "do-not-reply@domain.com", and I don't know any organizations that only allow one authorized outgoing mail address.